# Where is wrong with this fake proof that Gaussian integer is a field?

Tags: fake-proofs, gaussian-integers

The Gaussian integer $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an Euclidean domain that is not a field, since there is no inverse of $2$. So, where is wrong with the following proof?

> **Fake proof**
>
> First, note that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a integral domain. Since $x^2+1$
>   is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is
>   maximal, which implies $\mathbb{Z}[i]\simeq\mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^2+1)$ is a
>   field.

Comment: $x^2+1$ is an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is not maximal. Note that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID.

Comment: Irreducible element generates a prime ideal, but not always a maximal ideal.

Comment: @CaveJohnson: An irreducible element doesn't even always generate a prime ideal!

Comment: @EricWofsey: in UFD, irreducible elements generate prime ideals. $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a UFD.

Comment: Oh no! First fake news, now fake proofs...

Comment: @Henrik Google "fake proofs" ... fake proofs are everywhere. SAD!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"Since $x^2+1$ is an irreducible element, the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is maximal"

Is this true in a generic integral domain? Consider the ring $Z[x,y].$ We have that $x$ is an irreducible element, but $(x)$ is not a maximal ideal, as it is contained in the ideal $(x,y)$ which is still not the entire ring.

Comment: I believe a counterexample in this particular case is $(x^2+1) \subsetneq (x^2+3,2) \subsetneq \mathbb Z[x].$

Comment: More generally, the ideal $(x^2+1,n)$ is an ideal strictly containing your ideal for any integer n. "Most" of the time, this isn't even a maximal ideal., (unless n is a prime congruent to one  mod 4). This ties in totally with the fact that Z[X]  is a two dimensional ring.

Answer (score 7):

$(x^2+1)$ is a prime ideal but not maximal.

it happens in a ring of Krull-dimension $\geq 2$. $\dim \mathbb{Z}[X] = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement that $(x^2+1)$ is maximal is false.

The maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z[x]$ are of the form $(p, x)$ where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: The maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are actually of the form $(p,f),$ where $f\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible modulo $p.$